AT32F403AVGT7 how to set CAN baud rate for this controller
I am using AT32F403AVGT7 controller but I am not getting any CAN response due to incorrect baud rate. Does anyone know how to set baud rate for this controller? I will share my code below:
error_status can_baudrate_set(can_type* can_x, can_baudrate_type* can_baudrate_struct)
{
  error_status status_index = ERROR;
  uint32_t wait_ack_index = 0x00000000;
  /* exit from doze mode */
  can_x->mctrl_bit.dzen = FALSE;

  /* request freeze mode */
  can_x->mctrl_bit.fzen = TRUE;

  /* wait the acknowledge */
  while((!can_x->msts_bit.fzc) && (wait_ack_index != FZC_TIMEOUT))
  {
    wait_ack_index++;
  }

  /* check acknowledge */
  if(can_x->msts_bit.fzc)
  {
    can_x->btmg_bit.brdiv = can_baudrate_struct->baudrate_div - 1;
    can_x->btmg_bit.rsaw = can_baudrate_struct->rsaw_size;
    can_x->btmg_bit.bts1 = can_baudrate_struct->bts1_size;
    can_x->btmg_bit.bts2 = can_baudrate_struct->bts2_size;

    /* request leave freeze mode */
    can_x->mctrl_bit.fzen = FALSE;

    /* wait the acknowledge */
    wait_ack_index = 0;
    while((can_x->msts_bit.fzc) && (wait_ack_index != FZC_TIMEOUT))
    {
      wait_ack_index++;
    }

    /* check acknowledged */
    if(can_x->msts_bit.fzc)
    {
      status_index = ERROR;
    }
    else
    {
      status_index = SUCCESS ;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    status_index = ERROR;
  }

  /* return the status of baudrate set */
  return status_index;
} 


Are there no TQ settings for bit timing? CAN controllers usually set this up at the same time as you set the baudrate. And well, picking such an exotic brand of MCU sounds like self-torture... what's documentation like, are there any app notes or code examples at all?
